# Drupal 7 - Custom module doesn't work

Tags: 7, nodes

i've wrote custom module for my site, but it doesn't work. 
It should transform shortcode from my text field:

> Example text [gap=word,5] example.

to the input.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
function game_gaps(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
    $subject = $node->field_gaps[$node->language][0]['value'];
    preg_match_all("^\[gap=(.*?)\]^", $subject, $fields, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $text = $node->field_gaps[$node->language][0]['value'];
    $text2 = str_replace("<p>", "", $text);
    $array = explode("</p>", $text2);
    $rows = count($array);
    $j = 1;
    $node->field_gaps[$node->language][0]['value'] = "";
    foreach ($array as $array2) {
      $gap = $array2;
      foreach($fields[1] as $value) {
        $fieldsVars = explode(",",$value); 
        if (preg_match("^\[gap='.$value.'\]^", $array2, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) == 1) {
          $gap = str_replace("[gap=" . $value . "]", "<input type=\"text\" size=\"" . $fieldsVars[1] . "\" value=\"\" data-for=\"" . $fieldsVars[0] . "\" />", $gap);
        }
      }
      if ($j < $rows) {
        $node->field_gaps[0]['value'] .= '<p>' . $j . '.&nbsp;' . $gap . '</p>';
        $node->field_gaps[0]['value'];
      }
      $j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas friends?

Comment: We'll need a whole lot more info to help you. 1) What is your .info file like? 2) Do you have a .module file? 3) Where / how is the game_gaps() function called? 4) Is it not working because the code isn't executed, or are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm trying to convert this module from the D6 version. This version has this:function gaps_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {

Maybe this will help?